# summing class values in jquery

Tags: jquery

what's the easiest way to sum values who all are in the same class

```
<div class='head'>
  <div class='title'>
    <div class='sumMe'>$1.01</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class='head'>
  <div class='title'>
    <div class='sumMe'>$2.01</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

sumMe = 3.02

Comment: How would you specify parents to make sure you are going down the right hiearchy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve this quickly using a jQuery [each](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) loop, the [Number()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) function, and the [isNan()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_isnan.asp) function just to be on the safe-side.

```
var sum = 0;

$(".sumMe").each(function(){
   var value = Number($(this).text());
   // or parseInt($(this).text(), 10);
   sum += isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
});

alert(sum);
```

Comment: Exactly what I was going to write. You should add the base (10) to your parseInt call though, since for certain numbers you'll get odd results otherwise (it guesses the base)

Comment: updated OP if i may, what if it's a float, do i still need the radix? Will i have to manually strip dollar sign?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var sumMeTotal = 0;
$(".sumMe").each(function(){
     //Use parseInt with a radix 10 
    var sumMe = parseInt($(this).text(), 10);
    sumMeTotal += sumMe;
});
alert(sumMeTotal);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var sum = 0;

$(".sumMe").each(function(){
   sum += +($(this).html());
});

alert(sum);
```

check working example here http://jsfiddle.net/RU8bm/